# Can't create x64 .exe file with GCC after NASM compilation on Windows 10 x64

Tags: windows, assembly, gcc, nasm, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to figure out, why i can't link NASM x64 `.obj` file into x64 `.exe` using `gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-win32-sjlj-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)`:

```
nasm -f win64 -o .\MyAsmProgram.obj .\MyAsmProgram.asm

gcc -march=x86-64 -mtune=intel -o .\MyAsmProgram.exe .\MyAsmProgram.obj

.\MyAsmProgram.obj:.\MyAsmProgram.asm:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `_printf'
.\MyAsmProgram.obj:.\MyAsmProgram.asm:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `_ExitProcess@4'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e):
undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then, i've tried to link `.obj` file with another GCC build  `gcc version 9.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC Build-20200227-1)`, but it failed too:

```
nasm -f win64 -o .\MyAsmProgram.obj .\MyAsmProgram.asm

gcc -march=x86-64 -mtune=intel -o .\MyAsmProgram.exe .\MyAsmProgram.obj

.\MyAsmProgram.obj: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Verbose output `gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-win32-sjlj-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-8.1.0/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw64 --with-sysroot=/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-win32-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64 --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-targets=all --enable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=win32 --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch-32=i686 --with-arch-64=nocona --with-tune-32=generic --with-tune-64=core2 --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='x86_64-win32-sjlj-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-win32-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-win32-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS=' -I/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-win32-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' LDFLAGS='-pipe -fno-ident -L/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-win32-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/opt/lib -L/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/lib -L/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/lib '
Thread model: win32
gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-win32-sjlj-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
COMPILER_PATH=C:/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/;C:/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/;C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/;C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/;C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/;C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../lib/;C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/;C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-march=x86-64' '-mtune=intel' '-v' '-o' '.\MyAsmProgram.exe'
 C:/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/collect2.exe -plugin C:/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/liblto_plugin-0.dll -plugin-opt=C:/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTiQ7aF.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-liconv -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt --sysroot=C:/mingw810/x86_64-810-win32-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64 -m i386pep -Bdynamic -o .\MyAsmProgram.exe C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/crtbegin.o -LC:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0 -LC:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc -LC:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib -LC:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../lib -LC:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -LC:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../.. .\MyAsmProgram.obj -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -liconv -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/crtend.o
.\MyAsmProgram.obj:.\MyAsmProgram.asm:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `_printf'
.\MyAsmProgram.obj:.\MyAsmProgram.asm:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `_ExitProcess@4'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Verbose output for `gcc version 9.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC Build-20200227-1)`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-9.2.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --disable-win32-registry --with-arch=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-build-format-warnings --prefix=/mingw --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --enable-nls --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC Build-20200227-1'
Thread model: win32
gcc version 9.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC Build-20200227-1)
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-march=x86-64' '-mtune=intel' '-v' '-o' '.\MyAsmProgram.exe'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/collect2.exe -plugin c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/liblto_plugin-0.dll -plugin-opt=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOKSdEK.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -Bdynamic -o .\MyAsmProgram.exe c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../crt2.o c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/crtbegin.o -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0 -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/lib -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../.. .\MyAsmProgram.obj -lmingw32 -lmingwex -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lmingwex -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmsvcrt c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/crtend.o
.\MyAsmProgram.obj: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`MyAsmProgram.asm`

```
global _main

extern _printf
extern _ExitProcess@4

section .data
    message:
        db   "hello, world", 10, 0

section .text
    _main:
        push    message
        call    _printf
        add     rsp, 8
        call    _ExitProcess@4
```

Comment: The immediate problem is that win64 does not use leading underscores, so remove all of those. That said, your program seems to be badly ported 32 bit code so it will not work anyway.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64414459/2189500).

Comment: The part with `file format not recognized` is because 32-bit MinGW GCC can't link a 64-bit object file into a 32-bit .exe.  (And apparently doesn't even recognize the `.obj` format).  The other link errors are due to leading-underscore stuff.  Also, 64-bit code uses the x64 SysV calling convention (which is caller-pops), not stdcall (or cdecl), so functions don't get decorated with `@4` (bytes of stack args they pop by returning with `ret 4`), because all functions return with plain `ret` (if they return at all.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've edited my code and now it works fine:

```
global main

extern printf
extern ExitProcess

section .data
    message:
        db   "hello, world", 10, 0

section .text
    main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 32

        lea     rcx, [message]
        call    printf

        call    ExitProcess
```

Thanks to [@Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547981/jester), [@David Wohlferd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189500/david-wohlferd), [@Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) comments.