# How to use syscalls on assembly in Windows

Tags: windows, assembly, winapi, nasm, system-calls

I'm trying to program with assembly on Windows, but it has been a huge pain, I'm trying to make a simple program that returns an exit code when it finishes but (opposite to Linux) there is no documentation on the syscall codes for Windows.

Therefore, I went straight forward to research how to do it, but there's little to no information about it, I've read that for making this syscalls I needed to include functions from libraries like: kernel32 or User32, but I can't link them into my programs because all of those libraries are .dll instead of .lib/.a and the linker obviously throws me the error that the libs don't exist, the next code is something (of the only things that show up in this theme was this video) that I've copied line to line from the video:

```
global _main
extern _MessageBoxA@16

section .text

_main:
    push 0
    push 0
    push hello
    push 0
    call _MessageBoxA@16


hello:
    db "Hello, World", 0
```

all this using the NASM assembler and the next command in the Visual Studio Build Tools environment **'vcvars32'**: **'link /entry:main /subsystem:windows main.obj user32.lib'**

That's all I've tried, I need to know how to link these libraries, how to import the functions from them, how to make the syscalls. All that just for making an exit code to a program with no functionality (or in the case of the above code to create a message box)

Comment: It's not clear: are you able to compile/link/run what you have here? The API function for setting the exit code is [ExitProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess), from kernel32.lib.

Comment: Windows syscall numbers are available (for example [here](https://j00ru.vexillium.org/syscalls/nt/32/)). They won't do you much good since they keep changing, I'm just mentioning this so you know there *is* a list of them.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError the code I've presented is an example I've copied from the video I mention(in the video it works for him), I couldn't find User32.lib nor Kernel32.lib, only the dll files

Comment: Trying to use syscalls on Windows is a terrible idea.  You can find the libraries for Windows in the [Software Development Kit](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/).

Comment: @DavidWohlferd ok, but how do I use it with assembly? What if I want to make a compiler, would I need that development kit inside my compiler? (just an example)

Comment: Well, to make a compiler, you'd need to do things like read and write files.  So maybe you could look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64414459/2189500), which shows how to use stdio functions.  That gets you fopen (probably easier to use than CreateFile).

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I'd said that it was an example (the compiler thing), I need to know how to link Kernel32/any windows specific library to my assembly code, because in my computer there is not a single .lib inside System32 and as far as I know, dll cannot be linked by the linker

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I've got it to work, now, if I link these libraries, will my program work on every version of windows? (if they maintain the same standard)

Comment: @NicoCano: Yes, assuming you use only functions that were available on that old a version of Windows, you can write a program that will run on anything from (say) Windows NT 4 up through Windows 11.

Comment: Compilers generally rely on a platform SDK (and tools such as link.exe, which are not default components of windows) being installed rather than including their own copy. If you're making your own compiler and linker, you don't even necessarily need .lib files. In principle importing a function from a dll only requires the name of the function and the name of the dll to import it from.

Comment: @harold how do I import from a dll the function I want? As you said in the comment above.

Comment: @NicoCano in the executable it [works like this](https://github.com/corkami/pics/blob/master/binary/pe101/README.md), if you're compiling directly to an exe file (so your compiler is also a linker) you can get those strings into the import table in any way you want

Comment: You can also use GetProcAddress (like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/getprocaddress?view=msvc-170)) to call functions from DLLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to download the SDK and grab the libs from there.

Comment: Good! You can mark your answer. That can be a solution to similiar questions.

Comment: That, or make your own. It's not like the [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)) for import libraries was incredibly complex.